# Counting text-items per page in MS access

Tags: vba, ms-access, report, counting

I'd like to count a text-string in every page on a report and print out the count of the strings in the page-footer.

Searching for a string in a text field is straight forward, counting the findings within the text-field too, but how is it possible to sum the findings in a integer variable per report-page when it has several entries?

i.e. I´ve got a report-page like this where each new line is a new record.
Here the first report-page:

```
aaaaaaF
aaaaaFF
ffaaaaaaaaa
FaaaaaFF
```

Now the page-footer:

```
There are 4 records. The letter "F" has been found 6 times on this report page.
```

Now the second report-page:

```
aaaFaaF
aaaaaF
fFaaaaaaaaa
FaaaFaFF
FFaaaaFa
```

page-footer:

```
There are 5 records. The letter "F" has been found 10 times on this report page.
```

I'd be happy if smdy has an advice for me.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First step is to figure out how many occurances of "f" occur in each record.  Which you can do using

```
= Len([myField]) - Len(Replace([myField],"f",""))
```

Now for the total occurances in that page you use the `Sum` function in a text box in the report footer section.

```
= Sum( ... )
= Sum(Len([myField]) - Len(Replace([myField],"f",""))) ' if report based on a table
= Sum([myCalculatedField]) ' if you use the occurance count formula in the query instead
```

If you need to total across the page there is a link detailing how to go about it here (you'll have to scroll down a bit)

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/summing-in-reports-HA001122444.aspx

Comment: This `Len([myField],"f","")` is wrong. Perhaps you meant to use InStr().

Comment: You're right in that its wrong.  It needs a `Replace`.  Editing answer to fix

Answer (score 0):

You haven't shown any of the expressions that you are using but, essentially, in the Report Footer you would include a textbox which uses your aggregate function:

```
=COUNT([SomeField])    'or
=SUM(iif(some condition, 1, 0))
```

where SomeField is a field in the detail section, or *some condition* refers to this field.

That is, you need to SUM (or COUNT) across the whole report by referring to field(s) in the details section. You do not do this by attempting to refer to the subtotals that you have in the page-footers - this won't work.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So it is not possible to SUM op by page-footers? Hmm...

Comment: If you refer to the control in the page-footer, it will only refer to the last page-footer (if there is only one page it will likely return #Error).

Comment: Thank you, this is also quite helping.